# sshpass wait for keyboard input

Tags: sshpass

When using sshpass how do I let it wait for keyboard input?

for an example 
sshpass -p mypassword ssh username@hostname

That will make the connection to the host.

When I run it I wanted the connection wait after the password is appended to the host until I press "enter" on my keyboard.

Many Thanks

Comment: Then what's the point of using sshpass?

Comment: Its dual authentication. After my nomal pass i have a random key to add it on.

Comment: take a look at [*sexpect*](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Its dual authentication. After my nomal pass i have a random key to add it on.

`sshpass` cannot do this kind of thing. You need something like [expect](/questions/tagged/expect), [pexpect](/questions/tagged/pexpect).